# Is Mac-book Pro Mid 2015 up-gradable?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, flash-memory

- Does the newest model of Mac-book pro 15 inch 256 GB (mid 2015)
  support Samsung's 950 pro NVM-E M.2 storage (512 GB)?
- Will it also improve  sequential Read & Write speed of the system as
  the later form of storage is NVM-Express ?

NOTE: I tried to look it up over google & SE but I couldn't find any mention of MBP Mid 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apple uses special blade SSDs. There are some aftermarket blades made/sold by manufacturers such as OWC. Please pay attention to get the correct blade. They differ from the blades for the MBP 2012.